# How to access to observables out of the subscribe method were are getted in Angular

Tags: angular, rxjs-observables

In ngOnInit() I call to getGastado() method where I iterate over an array of dates to obtain several data related to and fill 2 arrays that I will need later and are private properties of my class, so, accessible in all the code of my class, like a global variable

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

private gastadoRealizadoAcumulado:number=100;
private gastadoRealizado: number[] = [];

ngOnInit(): void {
 this.getGastado();
}

 getGastado(){
  let mes:string;
  of(...this.etiquetasEjeX)
  .pipe(
    concatMap(item=>
      zip(
        of(item),
        this.dataService.getGastadoRealizadoEnMesYAño(this.proyectoId,
         this.getMonthNumber(item.slice(0,item.length-4)),
         +item.slice(-4),
         this.acumular),

        this.dataService.getGastoPlanificadoEnMesYAño(this.proyectoId,
         this.getMonthNumber(item.slice(0,item.length-4)),
         +item.slice(-4),
          this.acumular)
        )
       )
      )
     .subscribe(([mes,gastadoRealizado, gastadoPlanificado])=>{
       this.gastadoRealizado.push(gastadoRealizado);
       this.gastadoPlanificado.push(gastadoPlanificado);
    });  
   }
```

When the observable of(...this.etiquetasEjeX) completes I have 2 arrays with the values calculated

Now I need to iterate over these 2 arrays to obtain another one but in ngOnInit If I try to access to this.gastadoRealizado array for example after this.getGastado() I have an undefined object because the asynchronism I assume.

Then. How can I access to any of these arrays generated in this.getGastado() after the method has ended?

Thanks

Here I have a demo code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjsangular-kintela?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the observable to an promise and await it.

```js
  async getGastado(): Promise<void> {
    const [mes, gastadoRealizado, gastadoPlanificado] = await of(
      ...this.etiquetasEjeX
    ).pipe(
      concatMap(item =>
        zip(
          of(item),
          this.dataService.getGastadoRealizadoEnMesYAño(
            this.proyectoId,
            this.getMonthNumber(item.slice(0, item.length - 4)),
            +item.slice(-4),
            this.acumular
          ),
            this.dataService.getGastoPlanificadoEnMesYAño(
            this.proyectoId,
            this.getMonthNumber(item.slice(0, item.length - 4)),
            +item.slice(-4),
            this.acumular
          )
        )
      ),
      take(1)
    )
    .toPromise();

    this.gastadoRealizado.push(gastadoRealizado);
    this.gastadoPlanificado.push(gastadoPlanificado);
    //  console.log(mes);
    //  this.gastadoPrevisto.push(this.getGastadoPrevisto(mes,gastadoPlanificado))
    //  console.log('this.gastadoRealizado: ', this.gastadoRealizado);
    //  console.log('this.gastadoPlanificado: ', this.gastadoPlanificado);
    //  console.log('this.gastadoPrevisto: ', this.gastadoPrevisto);
  }

  async ngOnInit(): Promise<void> {
    await this.getGastado();
    //Here I can not use this.gastoRealizado and this.gastoPlanificado to calculate this.gastoPrevisto in function of them
    console.log("this.gastadoRealizado in ngOnInit: ", this.gastadoRealizado);
    console.log(
      "this.gastadoPlanificado in ngOnInit: ",
      this.gastadoPlanificado
    );
  }
```

In your [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjsangular-kintela-x8hbpf?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Thanks but after await in ngOnInit() I only see one value in the arrays even removing take(1). Using subscribe I push each value emitted inside subscribe Method. With this promise the pushes are outside and I don't know when they run